Regular expression for user name
I want to write the regex for a user name. It should contain at least 8 characters, starting with an alphabet character and containing at least one uppercase, one lowercase and one digit, with a maximum of 30 characters.
I wrote this code for it:
const validateAccount = (inputUsername: string): boolean => {
    const regex = /^[A-Za-z](?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9_]{7,29}$/
    return regex.test(inputUsername);
};

But why the input "Jone1234567" is not accepted as valid?

Your regex requires that at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter occur after the first character. In the example of "Jone1234567" there is no such uppercase letter, so it is not accepted.
You can solve this by making the first-character test also in a look-ahead assertion, so that all subsequent assertions are made from the start of the input, and so also consider the first character:
^(?=[A-Za-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9_]{8,30}$

Alternatively, you could move all look-ahead assertions to the start of the regex pattern, and only consume the first character after those:
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{7,29}$


It took me half a day to work on it. Thanks for helping. It works nicely
